# How to launch rake tasks in a different rails app with rvm?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rvm

I have a rails app which will be used to set up another rails app.
I've got through git pulls and unzips using system() but I have a problem setting the second app up with the standard:

```
system 'cd ~/path/to/second_app/; bundle install'
system 'cd ~/path/to/second_app/; rake db:automigrate RAILS_ENV=production'
```

Both bundle install and rake seem to use the first apps code.
I've tried even to launch a specific rvm rake by passing the whole path to it:

```
system 'cd ~/path/to/second_app/; ~/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.1.2@second_app/rake db:automigrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

after that I get

```
 NameError: uninitialized constant ExceptionNotification
```

Which is not present after a standard login shell execution; I use the ExceptionNotification for sending error notifications through email.

```
 rake db:automigrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Whole path should definitely work

```
system 'cd ~/path/to/second_app/; ~/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.1.2@second_app/bundle install; ~/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.1.2@second_app/rake db:automigrate RAILS_ENV=production'
```

Please describe what is wrong after this line?

Comment: I've added details to the main question.

Answer (score 0):

Since it was a priority task for our team, I've made an ugly hack around it using net/ssh gem:

```
Net::SSH.start(host, user, :password => pass) do |ssh|
  ssh.exec! 'cd ~/path/to/second_app/; ~/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.1.2@second_app/bundle install'
  ssh.exec! 'cd ~/path/to/second_app/; ~/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.1.2@second_app/rake db:automigrate RAILS_ENV=production'
end
```

Its a 'working' solution but I still would like to ditch the ssh usage.